# Linux rename files based on input file

Tags: linux, bash, rename

I need to rename hundreds of files in Linux to change the unique identifier of each from the command line. For sake of examples, I have a file containing:

```
old_name1 new_name1
old_name2 new_name2
```

and need to change the names from new to old IDs. The file names contain the IDs, but have extra characters as well. My plan is therefore to end up with:

```
abcd_old_name1_1234.txt ==> abcd_new_name1_1234.txt
abcd_old_name2_1234.txt ==> abcd_new_name2_1234.txt
```

Use of `rename` is obviously fairly helpful here, but I am struggling to work out how to iterate through the file of the desired name changes and pass this as input into `rename`?

Edit: To clarify, I am looking to make hundreds of *different* rename commands, the different changes that need to be made are listed in a text file.

Apologies if this is already answered, I've has a good hunt, but can't find a similar case.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Unix & Linux (unix.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while read -r old_name new_name; do
    rename "s/$old_name/$new_name/" *$old_name*.txt
done < file_with_names
```

In this way, you read the *IDs* from **file_with_names** and rename the files replacing `$old_name` with `$new_name` leaving the rest of the filename untouched.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for. Did not know read splits on words, this will be very useful in general.

Answer (score 4):

```
rename 's/^(abcd_)old_name(\d+_1234\.txt)$/$1new_name$2/' *.txt
```

Should work, depending on whether you have that package installed. Also have a look at `qmv` (rename-utils)

If you want more options, use e.g.

```
shopt -s globstart
rename 's/^(abcd_)old_name(\d+_1234\.txt)$/$1new_name$2/' folder/**/*.txt
```

(finds all txt files in subdirectories of `folder`), or

```
find folder -type f -iname '*.txt' -exec rename 's/^(abcd_)old_name(\d+_1234\.txt)$/$1new_name$2/' {} \+
```

To do then same using GNU find

Answer (score 0):

I was about to write a php function to do this for myself, but I came upon a faster method:

`ls` and copy & paste the directory contents into excel from the terminal window. Perhaps you may need to use on [online line break removal or addition tool](http://textmechanic.com/text-tools/basic-text-tools/addremove-line-breaks/). Assume that your file names are in column A In excel, use the following formula in another column:

`="mv "&A1&" prefix"&A1&"suffix"`

or

`="mv "&A1&" "&substitute(A1,"jpeg","jpg")&"suffix"`

or

`="mv olddirectory/"&A1&" newdirectory/"&A1`

back in Linux, create a new file with 
`nano rename.txt` and paste in the values from excel. They should look something like this:

```
mv oldname1.jpg newname1.jpg
mv oldname1.jpg newname2.jpg
```

then close out of nano and run the following command:
`bash rename.txt`. Bash just runs every line in the file as if you had typed it.

and you are done! This method gives verbose output on errors, which is handy.